# Turn off Joomla debug mode

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a website with Joomla 2.5.8. There was an issue happening only on the production server, so I turn on the logs for a few minutes.

I went to **Global Configuration > Server >Error reporting** and change it from "Simple" to "Development".

The thing is, the logs generated are not in the same encoding as the rest of the website. So it basically broke it down. Front-office and back-office are unavailable.

**I need to turn off the debug mode without using the administration console.**

Does someone knows which file or database table to amend ?

The goal is to have a temporary fix, so I can access the admin tools and revert the broken setting.

Comment: I can't check it now but you should search for `$debug` variable in configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Since I see you turned on error reporting, you will need to edit the variable `$error_reporting`  within the `JConfig` class in the configuration.php file to: `public $error_reporting = 'default';`.

Comment: $debug is always '0'. I am heading toward JDebug or JConfig since it contains every configuration

Comment: You are right : $config = new JConfig(); $config->error_reporting = 'default'. It stops the website from freezing.

Comment: Figured it was one of them.  I have an older version of Joomla so the naming conventions are a little bit different.  Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks, just add the path of the file you edited in your answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: Since your comment below, is there any reason you have not marked this as answered?  What I stated above fixes your issue.  It's probably the preferred way as well...

Comment: Error reporting and debug mode are two completely separate things. One is a server setting one is an application setting.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer with a 20 minutes server downtime.

I opened **/includes/framework.php** and **/administrator/includes/framework.php** and added this line :

```
// System configuration.
$config = new JConfig();

// XXX : Line to add for a temporary fix
$config->error_reporting = 'default';

// Set the error_reporting
switch ($config->error_reporting)
{
    case 'default':
    case '-1':
        break;

    case 'none':
    case '0':
        error_reporting(0);
        break;
```

Then the administration console is available again and I can change the settings properly.

Comment: Why did you choose to do it in the framework.php?  I never would've thought of that.  Any particular reason?

Comment: I browsed all the files included since index.php. And the JConfig object is instantiated here. If I call error_reporting(0); before it will be overrided.

Comment: I would not recommend this as a permanent solution, though. You should just change the config file, as dougjore suggested (editing the `confituration.php` file in the root Joomla directory).

Comment: Sure the goal is to have a functional backoffice, so one can properly revert the settings.

Comment: @Lodder, there is a misunderstanding of the situation. It's not like disussing the best way to pimp Joomla ; more like "OMG production is down, I need a fix NOW". As the clean way (admin console) is unavailable, every solution is better than none. I did clean my mess after, by reverting the changes on the core module. For an analogy : When your tire is flat on the highway (critical situation), you swap it with the old spare tire in your trunk (temp fix). This allows you to drive to the next station to get a new pair and a parallelism check (clean solution).

Comment: What in the world? And what are you talking about? ANd what do you mean by core module?

Do you understand that configuration.php holds the setting for both debug (0 or 1) and for error reporting (probably you want simple or something). 

In no way should you ever be editing those files.

Comment: https://github.com/elinw/joomla-cms/blob/ram-test/installation/configuration.php-dist#L43   edit that line in configuration.php found in your Joomla root.  

Error reporting is not the cause of your problems however, although it can make it hard to read when you have a lot of errors or when they are on the blue background.

Comment: If you have another solution, please post it. Error reporting was in fact the cause of the problem, or heavily related as it causes a blank page with an encoding error. Changing $debug_mode in configuration.php isn't related with this issue.